# Need help on why my code read my input?? lab Fat-burning heart rate

Tags: python

why doesn't my code read the first input i put

```
def get_age():
    age = int(input())
    if age>=18 and age<=75:
        return age


    else:
        raise ValueError ('Invalid Age')




# TODO: Complete fat_burning_heart_rate() function
def fat_burning_heart_rate(age):
   heart_rate = (0.7 * (220 - age))
   return heart_rate


if __name__ == "__main__":
     age = get_age()
     heart_rate = fat_burning_heart_rate(age)
     try:
        age = get_age()
        print("Fat burning heart rate for a", age, "year-old:", '\n',
          fat_burning_heart_rate(age), "bpm")

     except ValueError as ve:
        print(ve.ages[0],
            "\nCould not calculate heart rate info.")
```

when i type in the input it doesnt read it for example if i type a number between 18 and 75 it ignores it but when i type a number outside this range it ends execution.

it doesn't read my input for example if i use the number 45 it wont read it i would just ask for another input

Comment: In your code you are asking for age twice. Before and inside Try section.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you are calling the get_age function twice before and inside the try, so just remove the firt call to the function.

```
def get_age():
    age = int(input())  
    if age>=18 and age<=75:
        return age
    else:
        raise ValueError ('Invalid Age')




def fat_burning_heart_rate(age):
   heart_rate = (0.7 * (220 - age))
   return heart_rate


if __name__ == "__main__":
     age = 0
     heart_rate = fat_burning_heart_rate(age)
     try:
        age = get_age()
        print("Fat burning heart rate for a", age, "year-old:", '\n',
          fat_burning_heart_rate(age), "bpm")

     except ValueError as ve:
        print(ve.ages[0],
            "\nCould not calculate heart rate info.")
```

Instead of delete the statement I assigned a value to age because if not you will see an error like: "NameError: name 'age' is not defined".
Don't worry about the value that you assign to the age variable, that value will be replaced by the one that is written in the input

Answer (score -1):

```py
def get_age(age):
    try:
        age = int(age)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    
    if type(age) is int and age in range(18, 76):
        return age
    else:
        print("Invalid Age. Please try again.\n")
        return get_age(input("Enter Age: "))


def fat_burning_heart_rate(age):
    heart_rate = (0.7 * (220 - age))
    return heart_rate

if __name__ == "__main__":
    age = get_age(input("Enter Age: "))
    print(f"Fat burning heart rate for a {age} year-old: \n{fat_burning_heart_rate(age)} bpm")
```

Output:

```
Enter Age: 45
Fat burning heart rate for a 45 year-old: 
122.49999999999999 bpm
```

Comment: This solution could result in a `RecursionError` exception if the user entered an invalid age repeatedly (although they would have to do so almost 1024 times with default settings)
  If you want to keep prompting until you get a valid input, use a while loop, not recursion.
 Or, purposely raise an exception for the caller to catch, as the OPs solution did.